# Finding the area enclosed by $px^4+qxy+ry^2+sy+t=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

When $px^4+qxy+ry^2+sy+t=0\ (p,q,r,s,t\in\mathbb R)$ represents a simple closed curve on the $xy$ plane, can we represent the area enclosed by this curve by $p,q,r,s,t$? If yes, then how?

**Example 1** : $2x^4-2xy+y^2+6y+5=0$ represents a simple closed curve. (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E4-2xy%2By%5E2%2B6y%2B5%3D0))

**Example 2** : $2x^4-2xy-y^2+6y+5=0$ **does not** represent a simple closed curve. (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E4-2xy-y%5E2%2B6y%2B5%3D0))

Comment: Perhaps treat the equation as a quadratic in $y$, and solve expressing upper and lower limits for $y$ in terms of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $ax^4-by^2\pm\ldots=0$ with $a,b>0$ is an open curve pretty much for the same reason that $ax^2-by^2\pm\ldots=0$ is an open curve as well, called hyperbola. Then all you have to do is compute

$y_{_{1,2}}(x)=\dfrac{-(s+qx)\pm\sqrt{(s+qx)^2-4r(t+px)^4}}{2r}$ , the area being $\displaystyle\int_v^w|y_{_1}(x)-y_{_2}(x)|~dx=$

$=\displaystyle\frac1r\int_v^w\sqrt{(s+qx)^2-4r(t+px)^4}~dx$, where *v* and *w* are the left-most and right-most values

of *x*, i.e., the extrema of $x(y)$, which are to be found amongst the roots of $x'(y)=0$. Granted, this type of integral does not usually possess a closed form expression, and even the exact values of *v* or *w* are hard to come by.

Comment: OK. I expected that there would be an 'amazing' way to find the area, but there seems no such way. Anyway, thank you. (by the way, I think you want to write $-4r(t+px^4)$ instead of $-4r(t+px)^4$.)